# Titanium : access analytics via API?

Tags: titanium, analytics, titanium-alloy

I am using the Titanium mobile library (with the Alloy framework), and I have started tracking custom events by using the `Ti.Analytics.FeatureEvent()` function.  I'd like to be able to retrieve the data that I have sent to Appcelerator via an API. is this possible? I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

As a Appcelerator Studio user you can use https://dashboard.appcelerator.com and there you can see all your analytics events in real time the only thing here is that you have to pay for this service you have to had a enterprise account, I wasn't able to retrieve any analytics data with my free account, also if you have some custom properties in the featureEvent() function like this:

```
analytics.featureEvent('Reservation.careType', { 
        type : careType
    });
```

I'am still not able to see my "type" value in the ticket that i raised they've told me that they can send that data with an http://aws.amazon.com/s3/ account.

Hope this helps